# FIFO queue in JDK

Tags: java, collections

I want to have a **limited queue with FIFO**. So if maximum size of queue exceeds, first element(s) are removed.

**FIFO queue with google collections:**

```
Queue<Integer> fifo = EvictingQueue.create(2); 
fifo.add(1); 
fifo.add(2); 
fifo.add(3); 
System.out.println(fifo);  // prints [2, 3]
```

**FIFO queue with apache collections:**

```
// FIFO-queue works with apache collections
Queue<Integer> fifo2 = new CircularFifoQueue<>(2);
fifo2.add(1);
fifo2.add(2);
fifo2.add(3);
System.out.println(fifo2); // prints [2, 3]
```

**FIFO queue with JDK collections:**

```
Queue<Integer> fifo3 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);
fifo3.offer(1);
fifo3.offer(2);
fifo3.offer(3);
System.out.println(fifo3); // prints [1, 2]
```

`ArrayBlockingQueue` does not work as FIFO, it only stops inserting elements if queue is full.

**Are there any JDK FIFO queues working similar to `EvictingQueue` or `CircularFifoQueue`?**

And if JDK does not provide something like that, which one should I take: `EvictingQueue` or `CircularFifoQueue`? 
Which is better implemented?

*(Please dont provide example implementation of fifo queues, I want to use lib, preferable only JDK)*

Comment: What about `ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2, true)` ? It would be FIFO.

Comment: @anatoli no, does not work. It `prints [1, 2]` instead of `[2, 3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the ArrayBlockingQueue's offer implementation, it has a line, so value 3 is not even appended to the items array.

```java
if (count == items.length)
  return false;
```

So you can do this:

```java
static void append(Queue<Integer> fifo, int i) {
  if (!fifo.offer(i)) {
      fifo.poll();
      fifo.offer(i);
  }
}

// in main:
Queue<Integer> fifo3 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);
append(fifo3, 1);
append(fifo3, 2);
append(fifo3, 3);
System.out.println(fifo3); // prints [2, 3]
```

Comment: So it seems, JDK does not provide a queue implementation where first elements are removed automatically if size exceeds. The end result with your `append()`, the `CircularFifoQueue` and `EvictingQueue` is the same, still I dont know the pitfalls between those..all are bounded and blocking queues, so I guess, I will use your `append()`-method instead of the others..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JDK does provide a FIFO queue, but with no size limit (so no circular queue), and it's the `LinkedList` class.

Like the [javadoc says about `Queue` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html):

> **Queues typically, but do not necessarily, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner**. [...] **Whatever the ordering used, the head of the queue is that element which would be removed by a call to remove() or poll().** In a FIFO queue, all new elements are inserted at the tail of the queue. Other kinds of queues may use different placement rules. **Every Queue implementation must specify its ordering properties.**

And from the [`LinkedList` doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) we know that the `add` method "appends the specified element to the end of this list", so calling `add/offer` will insert an element at the tail of the queue, while `remove/poll` will get an element from the head.

So, if you don't need a fixed size queue, you can use:

```
Queue<Type> q = new LinkedList<Type>();
q.add(elem1);
q.add(elem2);
q.add(elem3); // [elem1, elem2, elem3]
q.remove(); // [elem2, elem3]
```

Otherwise, you can just use Robert implementation.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. For my case, I need a bounded queue. However, it`s strange that no queue-implementations provide a method to get its tail (=the last element in the queue).

Comment: The Queue interface doesn't provide it, however LinkedList does. `remove()/poll()` will extract the element from the head, while `remove​(int index)` will extract an element from an arbitrary position; if you need to extract quickly the tail, you can use `pollLast()`

Comment: @nimo23 A FIFO/`Queue` clearly is a data structure which can only insert at one end and remove from the other. If you want a data structure which also allows to get the last element, you are looking for a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html), which stands for “double ended queue”. When you follow the link, you’ll see that there are multiple implementations and I’d prefer `ArrayDeque` over `LinkedList`, especially as you know the intended capacity before-hand. When strictly enforcing the maximum size, it *is* a circular fifo queue.